# Modifying the dimensions of a pie chart (Google Chart Tools)

Tags: google-visualization

**Short version** - I want to modify the width/height of a [`google.visualization.PieChart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) object after construction, but I can't find any documentation pointing out how it's done.

**Context** - I'm building a visualization that overlays a bunch of data on a Google Map. At certain lat/long coordinates I want to render a pie chart marker detailing certain statistics that are relevant to that place.

To avoid cluttering up the screen, I want to vary the dimensions of the pie chart markers based on the current zoom level. This requires me to either re-render all markers that are currently visible or, preferably, change the width/height attributes of all markers.

[image: Pie chart on Google Map]

I currently use the following settings to render my charts:

```
        legend: {position: "none"},
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        pieSliceText: "none",
        colors: ["#C10001", "#F79647", "#92D051", "#558ED5", "#7F7F7F"],
        tooltip: {textStyle: {fontSize: 14}}
```

Is there a way to alter the dimensions of the chart after it's created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution I have so far is to redraw the entire chart with changed width/height settings. This snippet uses jQuery.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
    var drawingOptions = $.extend({}, defaultDrawOptions);
    drawingOptions.width = defaultDrawOptions.width*(currentZoom/defaultZoom);
    drawingOptions.height = defaultDrawOptions.height*(currentZoom/defaultZoom);

    dataPoints[i].chart.draw(dataPoints[i].dataSource, drawingOptions);
}
```

As you can see, this half-baked solution is rather clumsy and might needlessly deteriorate performance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there's something in the API; nevertheless with a tiny bit of Javascript you should be able to modify the attribute of the SVG tag containing the chart. One possible way is to add a viewBox attribute that will scale up or down the pie chart.

Comment: Interesting tip, but when I modify the `svg` tag in Firebug it doesn't maintain its position on the map. I've created screenshots of the chart in its [normal state](http://i.imgur.com/F54Ni.png) and its [scaled down state](http://i.imgur.com/HIOh6.png). I want to render these charts at a specific location, so I need them to scale around their center point.

Comment: How about changing the x/y as well of the viewBox; if not fine then I guess you would need more work to modify the content of the SVG to be able then to apply your transform.

Comment: [Like this](http://i.imgur.com/pIMGF.png)? I only see the top left quarter of the pie when I do this.

Comment: How can setting a negative X/Y minimum help fix the issue? I don't quite follow. In any event, [this viewBox setting](http://i.imgur.com/2Ec16.png) yields no visible result.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to play around with viewBox and use the right value according to your image that I do not have (100 is an example). Changing its origin might fix your issue with the image being shifted. As I said, I guess the right way would be to add an extra <g> and apply a <transform> - in that case you'll have full control.